# как получить данные из БД в Yii-2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Вот таким образом я получаю данные из БД средствами PHP.

```
//Чтение из БД
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT question FROM users");

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ 
    print("<br>".$row['id']); 
     //ТУТ мы делает что-то полезное
    }

//Освобождаем курсор  
mysqli_free_result($result); 
//Закрываем БД
$mysqli->close();
```

---

Я нашел этот метод в справочнике, но я не уверен что это тоже самое:

```
foreach (Customer::find()->batch(10) as $customers) {
   //$customers - это массив
}
```

**Вопрос:как получить данные из массива?** 
 **Как в Yii2, подобно в цикле `while` получать данные?**

Я пытался так но не получается:

```
echo $customers[0];
echo $customers['id'];
```

Массив возвращается вот такой через print_r($customers):

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [user_id] => 50 [login] => testlogin))
```

Comment: вы уверены что $custemers это массив? Что даст var_dump($customer) ?

Comment: @Sergalas Всё, уже разобрались. Спасибо вам за отклик. Приятного Вам дня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Customer::find()->asArray()->....
```

Если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Большое спасибо.  Кратко, понятливо, профессионально. Если бы еще добавили как получать данные из него, то было бы вообще супер. Тысячи людей вам бы сказало спасибо. Пример: `echo $customers[0]['user_id'];`

Comment: учитывая то, что возвращенный элемент является массивом, можно просто вывести его через `<pre><?print_r($customers)?></pre>`. И посмотреть в каком виде возвращается массив

Comment: @Василий Барбашев `Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 50 [login] => testlogin) ) `

Comment: foreach ($customers as $value) { echo $value['userId'] . ":". $value['login']; }

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
foreach (Account::find()->asArray()->all() as $customer) {
    echo "</br>".$customer['id'];
}
```